# Code executing after the form it is in has been closed and disposed

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms App that is functioning in a way that I do not understand. I have created a simple app to reproduce the functionality to minimum logic for clarity. It has two forms.

Form1:
There is a button1 that when clicked adds rows to a datatable. 
There is a button2 that displays a form and sends the datatable to the form.

Form2:
Form2 creates a dataview from the datatable and binds the dataview to a listbox. Form2 also has a button1 that does a this.Close() on the form. I read that anything opened with formName.Show() will be disposed of during .Close.

Here is where things are get weird. Form1 button1 can be clicked over and over each time clearing out the datatable and adds the rows again. Once from1 button2 is clicked and the form2 is displayed and then closed, going back to form1 and clicking button1 raises an error. The error is from the form2 (which has been closed) listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event.

The question is, why is an event firing for a control that is gone on a form that is gone?
I have found several ways to avoid this but I am wanting to understand why it is happening such as setting the listbox datasource = null but would like to know what is going on.. Spent half a day trying to figure this out. SO community, please educate me here.

Form1 code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Boolean bInitialLoad = true;
    DataTable dtHardware = new DataTable("Hardware");
    Form2 multiServerView = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtHardware.Clear();

        if (bInitialLoad == true)
        {
            dtHardware.Columns.Add("ServerName", typeof(String));
            dtHardware.Columns.Add("Environment", typeof(String));
        }

        DataRow drNewRow = dtHardware.NewRow();
        drNewRow["ServerName"] = "SomeName";
        drNewRow["Environment"] = "SomeEnvironment";
        dtHardware.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        drNewRow = dtHardware.NewRow();
        drNewRow["ServerName"] = "SomeName2";
        drNewRow["Environment"] = "SomeEnvironment2";
        dtHardware.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        bInitialLoad = false;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenMultiServerView();
    }

    private void OpenMultiServerView()
    {
        multiServerView = new Form2(dtHardware);
        this.AddOwnedForm(multiServerView);
        multiServerView.Show();
    }
}
```

Form1 Designer

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(308, 390);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 34);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(437, 296);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 33);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(679, 482);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    }
}
```

Form2 code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    DataView dvServers = null;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(DataTable dt1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dvServers = new DataView(dt1);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ServerName";
        listBox1.DataSource = dvServers;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Form frm in fc)
        {
            if (frm.Name == "Form2")
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("I am the listbox event from Form2");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Form2 Designer

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 113);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(749, 287);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // listBox1
            // 
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(291, 31);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(171, 69);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(653, 415);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 25);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form2_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you declare `Form2 multiServerView` at Form1 level rather than in `OpenMultiServerView()`? I think that may be keeping the form 'alive'.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.addownedform?view=netframework-4.8) for `AddOwnedForm` state _The form assigned to the owner form remains owned until the RemoveOwnedForm method is called._ Maybe try that.

Comment: @spodger Good question. I need to for other reasons I need to close and open form2 from form1 sometimes. That is why it is declared that way.

Comment: OK, I guess it's down to @JohnnyMopp's suggestion, then.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in the generated code. Would you mind including the designer.cs files? I think the event on form1 is attached by form2, but the handler is never removed

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp Just tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: @A. Chiesa I have included the designer file code. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I also tried this.Owner = null; in form2 just after initialization but I still get the same results.

Comment: What do you mean by "gone"? Garbage collected? Disposing an object doesn't immediately cause it to be collected, and even if it did `Form1` has two references to the `From2` that it creates... `multiServerView` and in `OwnedForms` so it can't be collected.

Comment: @Joshua Robinson Good point. I just tried adding `this.RemoveOwnedForm(multiServerView);` and  `System.GC.Collect();` before I modify the table in form1 where it is causing it to fire the event from form2. Still seeing the same result.

Comment: the form might be closed, I don't think it's disposed though, it's just closed ;)

Comment: If the code in the question is the latest version `Form1` still has two references to `Form2`. `Form2` can't be collected.

Comment: @Joshua Robinson Now I understand what you are saying. So is there a way to declare multiServerView  at the level I am doing it at and be able to get rid of it? I can avoid the problem by setting the listbox.datasource = null; when form2 is closing, just not sure if that is the best way to do it. Or maybe I should just add the datatable contents manually instead of binding the table to the listbox..

Comment: @MatthewD you could set `multiServerView = null` when you call `RemoveOwnedForm`, but bear in mind that it won't immediately collect if you do that. You'll also have to start checking `multiServerView` for null everywhere that you use it. You could break the databinding when `Form2` closes like you describe, or if you don't need to create a new instance of `Form2` every time `button2` is clicked you could set it up such that `Form2` doesn't actually close and just Hides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the instance of `Form2` isn't actually gone. You are correct in assuming that it has been disposed, since you called `Show`, but it has not been collected by the garbage collector. In fact, it can't be collected because in the code example provided `Form1` has two references to the instance of `Form2` that it created.

The first is in `Form1.OwnedForms`. The second is the field `Form1.multiServerView`.

You said you had a few ways to fix it, such as breaking the binding when `Form2` closes, but I thought I'd just throw out this suggestion. If you don't actually need to create a new instance of `Form2` every time you show it, you could just create one instance of it in the constructor of `Form1`, handle `Form2.Closing` and just hide `Form2` when the user closes it.

So, something like...

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Removed bInitialLoad, we'll set up the data table in the constructor.
    DataTable dtHardware = new DataTable("Hardware");
    Form2 multiServerView; //No longer initalizing here, we'll do that in the constructor.

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dtHardware.Columns.Add("ServerName", typeof(String));
        dtHardware.Columns.Add("Environment", typeof(String));
        multiServerView = new Form2(dtHardware);
        AddOwnedForm(multiServerView);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtHardware.Clear();

        //Removed the check of bInitialLoad.

        DataRow drNewRow = dtHardware.NewRow();
        drNewRow["ServerName"] = "SomeName";
        drNewRow["Environment"] = "SomeEnvironment";
        dtHardware.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        drNewRow = dtHardware.NewRow();
        drNewRow["ServerName"] = "SomeName2";
        drNewRow["Environment"] = "SomeEnvironment2";
        dtHardware.Rows.Add(drNewRow);

        //Removed setting bInitialLoad.

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenMultiServerView();
    }

    private void OpenMultiServerView()
    {
        multiServerView.Show(); //Just show it.
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    DataView dvServers = null;

    //Removed the empty constructor since Form1 no longer needs it.

    public Form2(DataTable dt1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dvServers = new DataView(dt1);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ServerName";
        listBox1.DataSource = dvServers;
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am the listbox event from Form2");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form2_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Don't forget to wire it up in the designer!
        //If the user clicks "button1" or the "X" then just hide the form.
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, there is only ever one instance of `Form2` for `Form1`. You don't have to worry about instances of `Form2` that are disposed but not collected yet triggering events when something on `Form1` alters the data source.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the garbage collection point I was missing Joshua. Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, Matthew! Glad I was able to help.